# Do non-reflexive relations exist?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

I may be talking complete and utter trash here, but does there exist any relation that isn't by definition reflexive? I know anything must always be equal to itself but is there any way this can be shown as not true for a specific example?

Comment: The relation $<$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is not reflexive.

Comment: Of course. Take $R=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}|a=b+1\}$ for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relation "$x$ and $y$ are not equal" on any set.

The relation "$x>y$" on a set of real numbers.

The relation "$x$ is the boss of $y$" on the set of people.

Comment: Silly me, of course!

Comment: These relations are not only non-reflexive but (stronger) are irreflexive.

Comment: @drhab The last one arguably isn't.

Comment: @JackM Ah... You are your own boss of course :).